# How to reduces number of sqls generating Django restful services

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I need help to improve API performance. Below is my approach also i have tried to do other combination of fields with select_related or  prefetch_related but still i am getting like 400sqls.

## model.py

```
    class VisVisits(models.Model):    
            visit_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
null=True)
            class Meta:
                managed = False
                db_table = 'vis_visits'

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.visit_id)

    class VisVisitData(models.Model):

        vdata_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        app_local_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        visit = models.ForeignKey('VisVisits', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='data')    
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'vis_visit_data'

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.vdata_id)
```

## Serializer

```
class VisVisitDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
        model = VisVisitData
        field = '__all__'

class VisVisitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    data = VisVisitDataSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = VisVisits
        fields = ('visit_id','data')
```

## views.py

```
visit_data = VisVisits.objects.filter(is_valid=1,user_id=u).prefetch_related('school_program__school')
visit_data_serializer = VisVisitsSerializer(visit_data,context={'request':request},many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of queries you must prefetch the data that you serialize in the `VisVisitsSerializer`, i.e. `data`. In this serializer you don't include `school_program` so it's not necessary prefetch this. You can use the django debug toolbar (https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to inspect the repeated queries and find out what to put in `select_releted`/`prefetch_related`